# How to join 2 Datasets in a way similar to RDD?

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 data frames

```
val a = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 5).toSeq.toDF("key", "value")
val b = Map(1 -> 4, 2 -> 5).toSeq.toDF("key", "value")
```

I join them on the column `key`

```
a.join(b, "key").show(false)

+---+-----+-----+
|key|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|1  |2    |4    |
+---+-----+-----+
```

I would instead like the result

```
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|1  |{2, 4}    
+---+-----
```

I would like the column `value` to be an array that aggragates the values. Is there an idiomatic way to do this? The `join` on 2 RDDs does this by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go the fully typed route, you could go the Dataset route:

```
case class MyKeyValuePair(key: String, value: String)
case class MyOutput(key: String, values: Seq[String])

val a = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 5).toSeq.toDF("key", "value").as[MyKeyValuePair]
val b = Map(1 -> 4, 2 -> 5).toSeq.toDF("key", "value").as[MyKeyValuePair]

val output = a.joinWith(b, a("key") === b("key"), "inner").map{
  case ( pair1, pair2 ) => MyOutput(pair1.key, Seq(pair1.value, pair2.value))
}

output.show
+---+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|key|values|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+---+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|  1|[2, 4]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+---+------+
```

This gives you fine grained control over what you want your output to exactly look like, and gives you compile-time safety. You just have to define some case classes to type your datasets with.

Hope this helps!